# Form Field Does Not Complete By URL In Iframe or Google Site - but does as independent web app

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications, query-string

I am trying to complete a form created in google app script web app via URL with the intention to display the field but be inactive and a UUID for form submit.

In web app testing the form is completed by URL eg: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwam4eZHPrs2ooVQLzJZgMcFb9gfXC2OPSq8f7Xkp9z/dev?fn=bob filling "bob" into field "fn".

However to remove googles *"This application was created by another user, not by Google.Terms of Service"* we put the web app in and iframe or link in google sites. This throws a spanner in the works.

Any advise will be much appreciated

```
    function doGet() {
      return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page").evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
    }
    
    
    function userClicked(userInfo){
     
      const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-7D4bXhm1Yx0ekRUmrwr8fTsdQ0dLtMI4gYG-THPUdk/edit#gid=0";
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
      const ws = ss.getSheetByName("data");
     
     ws.appendRow([userInfo.firstName,userInfo.lastName,userInfo.app,new Date()])
    
     // Logger.log(name + " Clicked The Button");
    
    }
    
    function include(filename){
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
    
    }
```

```
    <script>

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
          var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
          var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
        });

      document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",doStuff);

      function doStuff(){

        const userInfo = {};

        userInfo.firstName = document.getElementById("fn").value;
        userInfo.lastName = document.getElementById("ln").value;
        userInfo.app = document.getElementById("app").value;

        google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);

        document.getElementById("fn").value = "";
        document.getElementById("ln").value = "";

        var myApp = document.getElementById("app");
        myApp.selectedIndex = 0;
        M.FormSelect.init(myApp);

      }


    </script>
```

```
      <script>
        google.script.url.getLocation(function(location){

          document.getElementById('fn').value = location.parameters.fn[0]
          document.getElementById('ln').value = location.parameters.ln[0]
        })

        </script>
```

Comment: Please provide all of your `page` html as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to pass a query string parameter into a Google Apps Script web app embedded in Google Sites but this might be done by using client-side JavaScript on a "regular" web page.

Note: Use the `/exec` URL, not the `/dev` one.

```html
<body onload="loadIframe();">
   
    <div id="content">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <script>
    function loadIframe(){
        const url = "put_here_your_web_app_url" + window.location.search;
        document.querySelector('iframe').src = url;
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Related

- [Google Apps Script Gadget URL parameters are ignored when embedded in a Google Site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13680195/1595451)
- [google site: pass parameters to embedded script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21427058/1595451)
- [Google Apps script get Parent URL to iFrame in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46818753/1595451)

Comment: Brilliant - I had to figure out to use the page.html instead of the code.gs URL reference but eventually. Working as wanted. Many Thanks